# Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Data missing in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have an error message but I don't understand the problem ?

***"Unexpected data found. Unexpected data found. Data missing."***

Visibly, my problem is here ???

`"d-m-Y HH:ss"
" 18:00"`

```
$start_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y HH:ss', $request->date_revision_start . ' ' . $request->hour_start);
$stop_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y HH:ss', $request->date_revision_start . ' ' . $request->hour_end);
```

Here my code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
 {
     $request->validate([
       'date_seance' => 'required',
       'hour_start' => 'required',
       'hour_end' => 'required',
       'fk_motorbike' => 'required',
       'fk_former' => 'required',
       'fk_student' => 'required',
       'fk_typeseance' => 'required'


]);


$start_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y HH:ss', $request->date_revision_start . ' ' . $request->hour_start);
$stop_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y HH:ss', $request->date_revision_start . ' ' . $request->hour_end);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In createFromFormat method remove double letters.

```
'd-m-Y H:s'
```

I tested like this and it works

```
$date_revision_start = '20-05-2019';
$hour_start = '17:00';
$hour_end = '18:00';

$start_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:s', $date_revision_start . ' ' . $hour_start);
$stop_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:s', $date_revision_start . ' ' . $hour_end);

dd($start_time, $stop_time);
```

**Output**

1. date: 2019-05-20 17:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)
2. date: 2019-05-20 18:00:00.0 UTC (+00:00)

**Explanation**

You were formatting time incorrectly

```
dd(Carbon::parse($date_revision_start)->format('d-m-Y HH:ss'));
```

gives

```
"20-05-2019 1717:0000"
```

Comment: As a reference, [date() documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) contains a table with all the possible formatters each with a meaningful description and example

Comment: @Dino Numić: Thank you , it's OK now... :-)